# Why is the completion handler in UIAnimation of type ((Bool) -> Void)? And what is the purpose of the bool?

Tags: swift, uianimation, completionhandler

For example

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
        self.datePickerView.center.y = self.view.frame.height + (self.datePickerView.frame.height/2)
        self.datePickerOverlay.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (true) in
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: self.datePickerOverlay)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: self.datePickerView)
    }
}
```

I understand the completion block is a closure where you perform tasks you want to happen after the animation. What I don't get is the function of the bool. As you can see I put `true` where the bool should be.

However, I'm wondering what that bool is suppose to stand for and who calls that bool in `UIView.aniamteWithDuration()`.

Is the bool suppose to stand for `finished` (in the sense that once the animation complete `finished` will be true)? Or is the bool suppose to stand for success (in the sense that if the animation completes successfully `success` will be true)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration

Comment: I don't know why this compiles, since you are naming the parameter "true". Change it to something not reserved, like "finished", to be able to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Developer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration) says:

> A block object to be executed when the animation sequence ends. This
>   block has no return value and takes ***a single Boolean argument that
>   indicates whether or not the animations actually finished before the
>   completion handler was called***. If the duration of the animation is 0,
>   this block is performed at the beginning of the next run loop cycle.
>   This parameter may be NULL.